# How to increase kali linux terminal scrollback buffer size

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

My problem is the number of lines in kali terminal, it has too few lines to display a result. Some commands just exceed the line limit and the result disappears. So, my question is **how to increase the number of line displayed in terminal on kali?** (I'm not sure if it's called a scrollback buffer size.)

Note that I know there are commands like `more` or `less`, but sometimes those commands just don't work, so I'm looking for something similar to Ubuntu which you can set it easily through UI. (but I just couldn't find it on Kali)

What terminal emulator I'm using is "**Qterminal**"

Hope someone knows the answer, thank you in advance!

Comment: I have never had `less` not working as a pager. It would help if you could clarify what the actual terminal application is ("kali terminal" is not specific).

Comment: @Panki So, this is what I did on my HackTheBox lab machine:
mark@node:/tmp$ ./linpeas.sh | less

The result:
ESC[48;2;86;155;68mESC[38;2;98;177;78m▄ESC[48;2;96;173;77mESC[38;2;98;177;78m▄ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;
177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;177;78m ESC[48;2;98;178;78mESC[38;2;98;177;78m▄ESC[48;2;97;175;76mESC[38;2;98;177;78m▄ESC[
48;2;93;168;74mESC[38;2;98;177;78m▄
...

It's not readable.

Comment: @Panki and the terminal I used is ZSH, is that what you meant by "terminal application"?

Comment: `zsh` is a shell, not a terminal. I suggest researching basic terminology and concepts first before trying "hacking stuff".  What you are seeing are escape sequences (aka color codes), which is not a problem with `less` - but with your input data.

Comment: @Panki thank you for your suggestion. May I know what the question should be? so I can edit it, "How to increase shell scrollback size?", ...

Comment: The question is correct in itself - you need to understand the difference between a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) and a [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)). Once you got that, edit your question and tell us what terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: @Panki got it in .config folder. What terminal emulator I'm using is "Qterminal". What's next?

Comment: Add this information in your original question by editing. Read `man qterminal` or check the documentation (not familiar with this).

Comment: @Panki Okay. Thank you for your time sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Behavior -> History size

[image]

Comment: Omg that works! I'm an idiot, just couldn't see that option on the terminal lol Thank you very much Artem!